# Symfony: link from twig to another page

Tags: php, symfony

this code from my controller loads my first page:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/main")
     */
        public function indexAction()
    {
        $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
        $html = $templating->render('base.html.twig');

return new Response($html);
    }
```

I have a link in `my base.html.twig` :

```
 <a href="{{ path('options') }}">My options</a>
```

When link is pressed, I want to use my `@Route("/options")` and go to my options page.The question is how to do it correctly?Thanks.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/options")
     */
    public function showAction(){

    return new Response("This will be options page:");
}
```

Comment: Add a route name: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-name or use the default in the path function

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/options", name="route-name")
 */
public function showAction() {

    return new Response("This will be options page:");
}
```

Now use the name of the route:

```
  <a href="{{ path('route-name') }}">My options</a>
```